# Mimic human typing with emacs

Tags: video

I want to record some typing on a screen video using emacs and I'm wondering if there is something available in emacs to mimic human typing.
I imagine I feed it a line(region) of text and it is displayed in the buffer, character by character which a human can follow. A bit faster and without backspace correction than my live typing, but still a lot slower than just playing back an recorded macro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to use the function `sit-for`:

> (sit-for SECONDS &optional NODISP)
>
> Redisplay, then wait for SECONDS seconds.  Stop when input is available.
>   SECONDS may be a floating-point value.

So you could do something like that:

```el
(defun insert-like-human (text &optional delay)
  (let ((d (or delay 0.1)))
    (mapc (lambda (c) (sit-for d) (insert c)) text)))
```

You can call it with `M-: (insert-like-human "my text")` or `M-: (insert-like-human "my slower text" 0.2)`.

As mentionned by @zck, you could also use random delay to make it look more natural, eg:

```el
(defun insert-like-human (text &optional delay)
  (let ((d (or delay 0.2)))
    (mapc (lambda (c) (sit-for (cl-random d)) (insert c)) text)))
```

Comment: One could even use `cl-random` to make the time delay between two characters differ, depending how predictable you want it to look. For example, `(+ 0.05 (cl-random 0.2))` results in a random number between 0.05 and 0.25 seconds.

Comment: perfect! Thanks, now I only need some typing sound :-)

Comment: M-x play-sound-file (seriously!)